# mongodb group by multiple fields, return newest document with all fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a table with data that looks like the following

```
project  | environment | timestamp
----------------------------------------
project1 | dev         | 1644515845
project1 | dev         | 1644513211
project1 | qa          | 1644515542
project2 | dev         | 1644513692
project2 | qa          | 1644514822
```

There are multiple projects and each project has multiple environments. There are multiple timestamps associated with each (project, environment) pair which correspond to the last time changes were made to the project.

Is there a query to group by (project, environment), get the the entry with the newest timestamp for each combination of (project, environment), and then return the entire document?

Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "env": "$env",
        "project": "$project"
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "$max": "$timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

However, it should return the entire document.

My attempts can be found [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EAkOsCwVsFk) and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YCEMEoLLziJ)

The first attempt, does not return the entire document. The second Attempt returns the document with the wrong timestamp.

```
  {
    "_id": {
      "env": "dev",
      "project": "project1"
    },
    "doc": {
      "_id": 1,
      "env": "dev",
      "project": "project1",
      "timestamp": 1.644515845e+09
    },
    "timestamp": 1.644519211e+09
  },
```

Possible working solution here [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yiz4AD0Bjm6), although I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: The order of fields in the grouping matters - I think you are looking for project+env group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {
> "_id" : 1,
> "project" : "project1",
> "env" : "dev",
> "timestamp" : 1644515845 }
>
> Is there a query to group by (project, environment), get the the entry
> with the newest timestampfor each combination of (project,
> environment), and then return the entire document?

Here is the aggregation query to get the desired result. The query runs in the newer `mongosh` or `mongo` shell client.

```
// Define the aggregation pipeline with various stages.
var pipeline = [

// Sorting by project+env+timestamp gives the last document for each group (project+env)
// as the latest (highest) timestamp.
{ 
    $sort: { 
        project: 1, 
        env: 1, 
        timestamp: 1 
    } 
},

// Grouping on project+env, and get the last document for the group -
// this is the latest of the group - use the "$last" operator. 
// The aggregation system variable "$$ROOT" references 
// the current top level document (with all fields).
{ 
    $group: { 
        _id: { project: "$project", env: "$env" },
        // newest_timestamp: { "$last": "$timestamp" },
        newest_document: { "$last": "$$ROOT" },
    }
},

// Make the "newest_document" as the root (top leve) document.
{ 
    $replaceWith: "$newest_document" 
},

// Optionally, sort the documents by project+ env
{ 
    $sort: { 
        project: 1, 
        env: 1 
    } 
}
]

// Run the query using the pipeline
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few corrections,

- First, you need to sort by `timestamp` in descending order
- Second use `$first` operator while group to select the latest document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "timestamp": -1 } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "env": "$env",
        "project": "$project"
      },
      "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yiz4AD0Bjm6)

---

Another optional stage, use `$project`, `$unset` stage to remove from result `_id` field, because it is not needed,

```
{ "$project": { "_id": 0 } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RcyzPcUQeLx)

or

```
{ "$unset": "_id" }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5b9Cr6opS2x)

---

> For better performance you can create an index in `timestamp` field in descending order!

Answer (score 0):

Query

- we can use max on the document also like bellow without the need to sort and create an index (documents can be compared also based on order of their fields).

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71118128-2-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
  {"_id":{"env":"$env", "project":"$project"},
   "latestDoc":{"$max":{"timestamp":"$timestamp", "doc":"$$ROOT"}}}},
 {"$set":{"latestDoc":"$latestDoc.doc"}}])
```

The fast way to do this with index is described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#optimization-to-return-the-first-document-of-each-group) but in the example the `"_id"` has only 1 field, and the accumulator has the other field of the compound index (here you have 2 fields and in the accumulator we have `$$ROOT`), so group is not using the index.

I tried all answers,and all were slow, 9-10 sec on 1 million documents.Test them all your self to be sure, if you find a way to use the index in the group, send some feedback if you can.

Mongodb 5.3 will have also [$top](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/top/) for getting the top or the topN.